# Sum calculation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of regions of one country and their population

ex.

```
regions = [
    (region1, 300000),
    (region2, 452345),
    (region3, 454355),
    (region4, 543535),
    (region5, 2323445)
]
```

And the exercise says that I have to calculate the population of the country by summing up the all the populations of the regions. They told me it's a list, but how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by by elzell will do the trick, but to address what appears to be the source of your problem:

- The object `regions` is a list, but it is not a list of numbers; it is a list of tuples.
- This means that you cannot sum the populations of each region directly.
- To get the population of a region, you must first

  - identify which region you are interested in; this is the index of the list you will select. Then,
  - get the population of that region; this is the second field of the tuple.  For example, to get the population of `'region3'`,

    `region3_population = regions[2][1]`

  This works because region3 is the third tuple (index 2) of the `regions` list, and the population is the second element (index 1) of the region information tuple.

The answer given by elzell uses a generator

```
(r[1] for r in regions)
```

to give you the second element (corresponding to the population) of each region tuple, which yields a sequence of all the populations.  This can be summed in the manner you are accustomed to with lists of numbers with `sum()`.

Comment: Thanks for giving the explanation to my short answer :)

Comment: So what is r[1] for r in regions? Because I've only seen exercises ex. for x in a (a=[egg,33,lamp,77]. I've never seen a letter behind ''for'', can you explain that to me.

Comment: by letter i mean r[1]

Comment: r[1] gives the second element (index 1) of each item r.  The `for r in regions` part goes through every element in regions.  The result therefore returns the second element for every element in `regions`.  If I entered `list((r[0] for r in regions))`, I'd get `['region1', 'region2', 'region3']` etc., or if I entered `list((r[1] for r in regions))' I'd get `[300000, 452345, 454355]` etc.  (list() is necessary in this case because generators don't actually make all the elements until they are invoked.  To make elements directly use list comprehensions with `[ ]` instead of `( )`)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

```
regions=[('region1', 300000),('region2', 452345),('region3', 454355),('region4',543535),('region5', 2323445)]
result = sum((r[1] for r in regions))
```

Comment: you have helped so much, but can you explain me ''sum((r[1] for r in regions))'', what exactly carries out?

Comment: Sure: (r[1] for r in regions) is a so-called generator. It iterates over each element in regions, which means that r is first ('region1',300000), then ('region', 452345) and so forth, and yields of each of these r the second element r[1], which is the population. sum() simply sums up all elements that are yielded by the generator. Clear so far?

Comment: Oh ok, now  I get it, thank you again. I'm a freshman in university and one of my classes is python programming which I don't understand perfectly,so  I may ask you, for your advise again, is that ok?

Comment: Sure. By the way, Python is a great language, so keep it up!

Comment: I've posted another assignment, could you help me a little bit?